# Set width of gif file in img tag using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to add width attribute to gif file in img tag containing png and jpg using jquery.
Here is my code from which I want to select gif.

```
<article id="post195" class="abcd123">
  <div class="content">
    <div id='gallery' class='columns'>
        <dl class='gallery-item'>
            <dt class='gallery-icon'>
                <a href='/?attachment_id=195' title='gif(1)'><img src="http://qwerty123.com/images/testfile.gif" class="attachment" /></a>
            </dt>
        </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

By using this:

```
$("article").find('img[src$='.gif']').attr('width',500);
```

But it doesn't work.
Can anyone tell me where the problem lies?

Comment: How doesn't it work? Are you seeing any error messages? Or does the width not change?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string. With a little bit of effort and debugging from your side, you would have figured this out by your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes inside your `.find` around `.gif` since you start with single quotes:

```
$("article").find('img[src$=".gif"]').attr('width',500);
```

Comment: Actually, quotes aren't needed. They can be removed altogether.

Comment: I added this in footer:
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('document').ready(function($){
 $("article").find('img[src$=".gif"]').attr('width',500);
});
</script>

Comment: What to look in firebug?

Comment: In the "Console" tab.

Comment: I know your answer is right but it is not working for me, I checked the console but I don't know what to look into. I tried all tabs within console but haven't found anything related to this jquery script

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery is loading / firing...trying throwing a few `console.log("test");` statements before and after this statement.

Comment: I found it written test test in the console, now what to do?

Comment: Do you have any CSS applied on this image?

Comment: Yes, it is wordpress default

Comment: The CSS is probably over-riding this, change `.attr` to `.css` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Can't check the page, could you make a fiddle with the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("article").find('img[src$='.gif']').attr('width',500);
```

Is not valid syntax, as you're closing your quotes and putting invalid text in between. You should do it like this:

```
$("article").find('img[src$=".gif"]').attr('width',500);
```

You could also use `.css()` instead of `.attr()` if you want (`css('width',500)`)

Comment: Wrong, it is better to use the width/height attribute of an image rather than setting this with CSS. Moreover the method is not "CSS" but "css"

Comment: @galutrou I think it is a matter of preference which should be used, but css takes precedence over attribute declarations. So If the image has some other css width style set for it then changing the attribute won't help.